# "OpenGL error: 1282 - Failed to upload texture data" при загрузке шрифта с библиотекой FreeType для отрисовки в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Пишу простую программу для работы с библиотекой FreeType. Скачал исходники, скомпилировал библиотеку, так же добавил для работы с OpenGL другие необходимые библиотеки (GLEW, GLFW, GLM). Ниже привожу код:

```
#include <iostream>
// FreeType
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <freetype/ftglyph.h>
FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;
//OpenGL
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
//Инициализация и загрузка шрифта
void initFreeType() {
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        std::cerr << "Не удалось инициализировать FreeType" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "Arial.ttf", 0, &face)) {
        std::cerr << "Загрузка шрифта не удалась" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48); // Устанавливаем размер шрифта
}
void renderText(const char* text, float x, float y) {
    // Создание и настройка текстурного объекта
    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    if (tex == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to generate texture" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to bind texture" << std::endl;
        glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
        return;
    }
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    for (const char* p = text; *p; p++) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, *p, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to load glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        // Загрузка данных изображения в текстурный буфер OpenGL
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        GLenum error = glGetError();
        if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "OpenGL error: " << error << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Failed to upload texture data" << std::endl;
            glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
            return;
        }
        // Отрисовка квадрата с текстурой
        float x2 = x + face->glyph->bitmap_left;
        float y2 = y - face->glyph->bitmap_top;
        float w = face->glyph->bitmap.width;
        float h = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(x2, y2 + h);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(x2 + w, y2 + h);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(x2 + w, y2);
        glEnd();
        // Смещение позиции X
        x += (face->glyph->advance.x >> 6);
    }
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
}
int main() {
    if (std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8") == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set locale." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Инициализация GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to init GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Установка параметров контекста GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // Создание окна GLFW
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    // Создание контекста OpenGL и установка его в окно GLFW
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Инициализация GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to init GLEW" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    //Инициализация и загрузка шрифта
    initFreeType();
    // ---Основной цикл---
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // Очистка буферов кадра
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Рендеринг текста
        renderText("Привет, мир!", 100, 100);
        // Обновление содержимого окна
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        // Проверка событий и вызов обработчиков
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    // Освобождение ресурсов
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа компилируется и запускается, однако в консоль выводятся отладочные сообщения об ошибке: 
*OpenGL error: 1282 
 Failed to upload texture data*
А если убрать фрагмент:

```
GLenum error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "OpenGL error: " << error << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Failed to upload texture data" << std::endl;
        glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
        return;
    }
```

То выводится ошибка:
*Failed to bind texture*

Чуть позже добавил вывод значений face->glyph->bitmap. width, height, и указатель не = 0 и не пустые.

Comment: ¿Содержимое `face->glyph->bitmap` адекватное? т.е. ширина / высота положительные, буфер не нулевой указатель

Comment: Добавил вывод этих данных в консоль, значения: Width = 24, а Height = 30.
А так же указатель не nullptr, вот например его значение при одном из запусков программы - 0000023713FF1810.